# Делает ли добавление в проект reference-ов из .Net фреймворка его более тяжелым?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Делает ли добавление в проект *reference*-ов из *.Net Framework* его заметно более тяжелым? Или заметно более медленным? Или ущербным?

Имею ввиду те сборки, которые включены в *.Net Framework*.

На всякий случай, поясню зачем. Есть небольшой кусок кода, который выполняется только в *Debug mode*. Этот кусок я добавил самовольно, никто из команды меня об этом не просил. Если узнают, то могут попросить удалять. Но он мне сильно облегчает жизнь, а удалять и добавлять каждый раз не хочется, не удобно. Для того, чтобы этот кусок работал, надо подгрузить пару *reference*-ов из *.Net Framework*. В релизе этот кусок не задействован, но *reference*-ы остаются. Для упрощения жизни, я бы оставил эти *reference*-ы даже в *релизной* версии, несмотря на то, что они в ней не используются. Но, на сколько это критично? Не будет ли это ущербно в каком-либо смысле для *релизной* версии?

Comment: На всякий случай замечу, что всегда можно поправить сам `csproj`-файл, убрав ненужные reference при сборке релизной версии.

Comment: @SurfinBird, В смысле, в pre-build action?

Comment: Нет, просто добавьте аттрибут `Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"`для тегов `Reference`, которые должны «работать» лишь в Debug-режиме, либо вообще вынесьте их в отдельную `ItemGroup` и добавьте тег к ней (и, конечно же, не забудьте обернуть сам код в `#if DEBUG`-`#endif`). По идее, должно сработать.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Каждая сборка загружается в бегущее приложение лишь тогда, когда выполняется первый метод, референцирующий типы из этой сборки [1], [2]. (Если у вас создаётся экземпляр класса `B` из другой сборки в инициализаторе поля класса `A`, этот код с точки зрения CLR выполняется в конструкторе класса `A`.)

Поэтому неиспользуемые сборки не должны влиять на время пробега.

Я вижу минус от «лишних» добавленных сборок только в том, что Intellisense будет предлагать вам методы из этих подключенных сборок несмотря на то, что они вам фактически не нужны.

---

[‌1]‌: [Back to Basics: When does a .NET Assembly Dependency get loaded](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Nov/03/Back-to-Basics-When-does-a-NET-Assembly-Dependency-get-loaded).

[‌2]‌: [When exactly are assemblies loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21914746/276994)

Answer (score 3):

Добавлю, что лишние референсы также могут отрицательно влиять на время билда (как у вас на машине, так и на билд сервере) и на размер получаемого дистрибутива. Лишнего, конечно, держать не стоит.

---

И в качестве оффтопика:

> Этот кусок я добавил самовольно, никто из команды меня об этом не
>   просил. Если узнают, то могут попросить удалять. Но он мне сильно
>   облегчает жизнь

Это не есть образец поведения в команде. Поговорите с коллегами, объясните, почему вам нужен этот кусок. И скорее всего они либо с вами согласятся, либо подскажут другой путь решения.

Comment: ТС вроде упоминает «те сборки, которые включены в .Net Framework», то есть дополнительный деплой не нужен. Ну и без них должно работать.

Comment: Может быть и поговорю

Comment: @andreycha, поговорил, мне разрешили оставить этот функционал. Но вопрос спрашивал не зря, потому что получилось привести разумные аргументы в пользу того, чтобы получить разрешение.